# How to extract text before a period from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Say I have a string whose text is something like, `"mohdibrahim.tasal"`. I want to extract `"mohdibrahim"` from this string.

I've tried this code:

```
string updateUser1 = user1.Trim();
```

Is this the correct approach, or is there another technique I should be using?

Answer (score 11):

OK, lets assume i think i know what you want.

Try

```
string user = user1.Split('.')[0];
```

This will split the string on the '.' and return the last part.

Comment: I think the OP wants `string user = user1.Split('.')[0] to get "mohibrahim"

Answer (score 9):

This will return everything before the period(".")

```
string updateUser1 = user1.Substring(0,user1.IndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string updateUser1 = user1.Substr(user1.IndexOf(".")+1);
```

I haven't tested it though.

Comment: This will return everything *after* the first period, not before.